# Configure JanusGraph in .net by Gremlin

Tags: .net, gremlin, janusgraph

I have the sample code below. Please help me fill out "___" RegisterDeserializer, RegisterSerializer, WithConnectionPoolSettings. And why fill it out?

And is there a way from the code below, I add the database name call? To know which name database I am using?

```
        //GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient(server, new GraphSON2Reader(),
        //                                                 new GraphSON2Writer(),
       //                                                 GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType);

       GremlinServer server = new GremlinServer(options.Host, options.Port, options.EnableSSL, options.Username, options.Password);
                                          
        var client = JanusGraphClientBuilder
                    .BuildClientForServer(server)
                    .RegisterDeserializer(____,_____ )
                    .RegisterSerializer( ___,____ )
                    .WithConnectionPoolSettings(____)
                    .Create();

        _g = Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `JanusGraphClientBuilder` already comes with a good default configuration for JanusGraph so you don't need to call all these functions while building the client if you don't need any non-default config like registering your own serializers or changing connection pool settings.

So, you can create a client exactly like it's shown in [the README of JanusGraph.Net](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet/#usage):

```cs
var client = JanusGraphClientBuilder
    .BuildClientForServer(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182))
    .Create();
```

If you already have a `server` object, then it's really just:

```cs
var client = JanusGraphClientBuilder.BuildClientForServer(server).Create();
```

---

Now to your other question:

> And is there a way from the code below, I add the database name call? To know which name database I am using?

The JanusGraph equivalent of a database name is the graph name and the JanusGraph Server binds a graph traversal source to each graph that should be available. Clients access a graph via such a graph traversal source where the default graph traversal source is usually just called `g`.

If the graph traversal source you want to access is called `gNew`, then you can access is with JanusGraph.Net like this:

```cs
var gNew = Traversal().WithRemote(
    new DriverRemoteConnection(
        JanusGraphClientBuilder.BuildClientForServer(server).Create(), "gNew"));
```

Comment: I want to use GraphSON in JanusGraph, how do I declare it? Here is the declaration in the other: 
          // GremlinClient client = new GremlinClient (server, new GraphSON2Reader (),
         // new GraphSON2Writer (),
        // GremlinClient.GraphSON2MimeType);

Comment: JanusGraph.Net already uses GraphSON by default. What you do with your example is using the old GraphSON 2 although GraphSON 3 is already supported by JanusGraph. That only makes sense if you're using a really old version of JanusGraph but that version then isn't supported by JanusGraph.Net at all.

Comment: As for the authentication of the account and password, how will I do? Can you show me how to create the account and password of a database like sql side and then verify it? In JanusGraph

Comment: If I use the following code, then it produces an error: "ResponseException: InvalidRequestArguments: The traversal source [gNew] for alias [g] is not configured on the server.":
GremlinServer server = new GremlinServer ("localhost", 8182);
var driver = new DriverRemoteConnection (JanusGraphClientBuilder.BuildClientForServer (server) .Create (), "gNew");
             _g = Traversal (). WithRemote (driver);

Comment: Regarding authentication, you only need that if you have configured authentication in JanusGraph. By default, you don't need any authentication.

Comment: And for the error: If you haven't configured a traversal source with the name `gNew` on the server, then you of course can't use it. Just stick with my first example if you haven't configured any traversal sources on the server.

Comment: 1. How can I configure the transport source as gNew on the server? Whereas I use docker to run server (JanusGraph) and I don't know how to do that, please give me sample code. I'm really stupid.
2. Without authentication, security will not be secure. So I need a sample code to authenticate between JanusGraph and .net.
* I downloaded JanusGraph console package, but I can't run like the gremlin console so I run the server side of docker.

Comment: Please create new questions for these or ask on any other of [JanusGraph's community channels](https://github.com/janusgraph/janusgraph#community) as it's really hard to help you in StackOverflow comments and this goes beyond the scope of your initial question.